# How can one search TableDefs for linked tables?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado, dao

Looping through a set of TableDefs, how can one determine if each TableDef represents a linked table, as opposed to a local table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a linked table, the `TableDef.Connect` property contains the connection information.  But for a native table, the `.Connect` property is an empty string.

So you can tell which are which by examining `Len()` of `.Connect`

```vb
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
With CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In .TableDefs
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print tdf.Name, tdf.Connect
        End If
    Next
End With
```

That approach is simpler for me to remember than `tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedODBC Or tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedTable`, or the ADOX approach.  It is also much more concise than the ADOX approach.

Answer (score 6):

Based on http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/37117-finding-linked-tables.html (the linked code resulted in an infinite loop, so I modified it):

```
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
With CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In .TableDefs
        If tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedODBC Or tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedTable Then
            ' We found a linked table! Now, show its location.
            Debug.Print tdf.Connect
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Taken directly from http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/37117-finding-linked-tables.html, the ADO counterpart (unverified code):

```
Sub ListAllTables(cnn As ADODB.Connection)

   Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog
   Dim tbl As ADOX.Table

   Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
   cat.ActiveConnection = cnn

   cat.Tables.Refresh
   For Each tbl In cat.Tables
      Select Case tbl.Type
         Case "ACCESS TABLE"
            Debug.Print tbl.Name & " - Access table"
         Case "SYSTEM TABLE"
            Debug.Print tbl.Name & " - System table"
         Case "TABLE"
            Debug.Print tbl.Name & " - Native table"
         Case "LINK"
            Debug.Print tbl.Name & " - Linked table"
         Case "PASS-THROUGH"
            Debug.Print tbl.Name & " - ODBC DSN Linked table"
        End Select
    Next tbl

    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set cat = Nothing

End Sub
```